# PowerShell - Import certificate

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am simply trying to import a pfx cert to Cert:\LocalMachine\Root and Cert:\LocalMachine\My.
The problem is that I have to run the powershell as admin in order for script succeed.

```
Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath $CertificatePath -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\Root -Password $CertificatePassword -Exportable
```

If I am running this PS command line from Azure DevOps pipeline how can I run this as admin?

Comment: If you're hosting your own agents, you could run the agents' Windows Service as SYSTEM or some service account that's a member of an appropriately privileged group, such as local admins.

Comment: Hi, is there any update for this issue? Feel free to let me know whether my anwser helps.

Answer (score 0):

Take the "Powershell on Target Machines" Task. In the task you can add an admin user for execution.

Answer (score 0):

> If I am running this PS command line from Azure DevOps pipeline how can I run this as admin?

There are two solutions:

1.If you are using a self-hosted agent. You can reinstall the agent using an administrator account. The detailed steps are:

step1. Uninstall the old agent.

step2. Download and unzip the new agent.

step3. Run config.cmd as an administrator. Note that the configurations need to be consistent with the old agent.

2.Using a built-in task "PowerShell on target machines", which need you to provide

a) a comma separated list of machine IP addresses or FQDNs along with ports. Port is defaulted based on the selected protocol. Eg: dbserver.fabrikam.com,dbserver_int.fabrikam.com:5986,192.168.12.34:5986

b) The administrator's username and password.